# Are beta badges no longer being handed out for Stat Analysis?

Tags: discussion, beta

I'm new to A51 process.  Does the fact that SA is in a public beta mean that the beta badges are no longer being handed out?  Just curious.  Couldn't find anything about it in the A51 faq -- I can ask this there if that would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just from reading the description next to the badge, it does look like Beta badges were awarded for private beta only - which ended here quite some time ago.

Comment: hehe.  Missed that.  OOps

Comment: plus some activity.